# is there anyway to convert xml into string or html in java?

Tags: java, xml, spring

how can i convert xml into plain text or in html format in java/spring

following is my email template

```
    <?xml version = '1.0'?>
    <m name="cpt">

    Dear Customer,

    find below details [Dynamic Value].

    [Dynamic Values.]

    Thanks,

    cpt page
    </body>
    </email>
```

i have one methhod

```
    String email = getXmlTemplateInStringFormat()
```

which gives me xml in string format like the one in following
sample Xml outPut

```
        <?xml version = '1.0'?>
        <m name="cpt">

        Dear Customer,

        find below details For xyz product.

        info

        details:

        First Value             fValue
        Title                   xyz
        Second Value            svalue
        Third V                 A and B
        email                   abc@xyz.com
        date                    11/11/2011

        address:

        email                   abc@xyz.com
        mobile                  2382919xxxx
        Fv                      dummyValue
        Country                 xyz


        Order

        Number              zxc123
        date                11/11/2011
        order no            cbz21us
        Total               40



        Thanks,

        cpt page
        </body>
        </email>
```

i want output should be like this without any xml tag

```
        Dear Customer,

        find below details For xyz product.

        info

        details:

        First Value             fValue
        Title                   xyz
        Second Value            svalue
        Third V                 A and B
        email               abc@xyz.com
        date                11/11/2011

        address:

        email                   abc@xyz.com
        mobile              2382919xxxx
        Fv                  dummyValue
        Country         xyz


        Order

        Number              zxc123
        date                11/11/2011
        order no        cbz21us
        Total               40



        Thanks,

        cpt page
```

how can i acheive this output?

Comment: Cut first 3 lines and last 2 ??

Comment: i cant..i am getting this string from rest call so i need to find the another solution.and this xml also uses for other purpose

Comment: What keeps you from changing the string after you got it?